# JQuery .on() method not binding to all elements in Phonegap app on Android 4.0

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have the following code. It seems to work fine, in as that all image elements are clickable on all ios devices and newer Android, but only elements that are visible on screen when the page is loaded are clickable on Android 4.0.

```
 $('a.openMediaDetails').on('click', function() {
```

Here is the code in context.

```
var HTML = [];
            var jsonParse = JSON.parse(evt.target.result);
            $.each(jsonParse.MediaList, function(mediaDataIndex, mediaDataVal) {
                HTML.push('<div class="item1"> <a data-transition="slide" data-mediaurl="', mediaDataVal.BigImageUrl, '" data-caption="',mediaDataVal.Caption,'" class="openMediaDetails"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,', mediaDataVal.ThumbBase64String, '" class="image" alt=""/></a> </div>');
            });
            $('#media-list1').html(HTML.join(''));
            //$('#media-list .item:last, #media-list .item:nth-last-child(2)').addClass('disBorderBottom');

            HTML.length = 0;

            $('a.openMediaDetails').on('click', function() {
                var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
                var states = {};
                states[Connection.NONE] = false;
                if(states[networkState]===false){
                    alert('No network connection');
                    $('.openMediaDetails').removeAttr('href');
                }else{
                    $('.openMediaDetails').attr('href', '#imageDetails');
                    $('#imageDetails #mediaDetailsImage').attr('src', $(this).data('mediaurl'));
                    $('#imageDetails .download').attr('href', $(this).data('mediaurl'));
                    $('#imageDetails #image_caption').html($(this).data('caption'));
                }
            });
```

Comment: You surely need to [delegate event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thank you everybody for the suggestion to delegate the event, I tried updating the line to:   `$('body').on('click','a.openMediaDetails', function() {` but the same problem still exists. As I mentioned the code works as expected on newer mobile OS, but not on Android 4.0.

Comment: Do see any error en the console ? ( chrome://inspect in google chrome )

Comment: I'm very new to Cordova development. I tried using chrome://inspect before posting, but my app wasn't showing up, the device is discovered, and chrome processes on the device show up but I can't seem to debug the Cordova app. Some posts on SO are saying that minimum version of Android for Chrome remote debug for Cordova App is 4.2 perhaps that's my issue.

Comment: When it's installed, you cant; but if you run `cordova run android --device` it will debug ( you need debug mode enabled )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Toni for pointing me in the direction that solved my problem. I couldn't use the Chrome remote debugging tools on Cordova App on my phone because it was pre Android version 4.4. I Googled around for a solution and came across Crosswalk https://crosswalk-project.org/ which installs a Chromium webview on Android devices pre 4.4. This allows consistent interfaces on old and new devices. Solved many odd rendering issues I was having with this app by just installing Crosswalk. I am also able to remote debug using Chrome with my old phone. Thank you all for your input. I am accepting this as my answer because it fixes my particular issue with inconsistent rendering on older Android devices, but the answers regarding delegating properly with the jQuery .on() method were also great.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically loaded elements use `.on()` in following way

```
 $(document).on('click','a.openMediaDetails', function() {
```

**[For more information - .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Answer (score 1):

I you are updating the DOM and those elements you select are being updated, you should bind the event with a parent element

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.openMediaDetails', function() {
  // you code here
});
```

Or if there is a parent element that won't change. You could indicate the parent, then is faster

```
 $('.parent').on('click', 'a.openMediaDetails', function() {
  // you code here
 });
```